# How do I return a new list from a function in scala?

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

For educational purposes I want to implement a filter function, which takes a filter like (_ > 4) and a list as parameters. It should return the filtered list. Basically it should do the same as the already available list.filter function, but I want to implement it myself. 
The question is how do I create a new list from within the function. I don't want to change the list from the parameter and so I think that's the only way to do this.

Comment: Recursion + pattern matching. - Give it a try and if you get stuck post what you tried and we will be more than happy to help. - bonus point, doing it using a tail-recursive algorithm _(first do it using normal recursion):

Comment: Hmm that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: A scala list is already immutable so, you can not really modify it, you have to create a new one. And that is usually done using recursion, that is the basic example, are you following any tutorial or book or something? I could give you the code _(it is like 3 lines)_ but that won't help you too much if you want to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Here is very simple example. It is not optimal, you can still improve it.

```scala
val list1 =  List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

def filter(list:List[Int], predicate:Int => Boolean):List[Int] = list match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case head :: rest => 
    val frest = filter(rest, predicate)
    if (predicate(head)) head :: frest else frest 
}

println(filter(list1, _ > 2)) //List(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
println(filter(list1, _ %2 == 0)) //List(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/yvLEnYL/7

To understand it you should read about recursion and pattern matching in scala. Trick here is this `case head :: rest =>` part that takes care about spiting list to first element and rest (rest can be empty list `Nil`). There is lot of materials about that for example there is great course in coursera that covers such topics (https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1).

Comment: Since it is clear that OP is learning, it would be great if you can explain what the code is doing ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I don't really have to create a new list, do I? Something like "case head :: rest => if (predicate(head)) head :: filter(predicate, rest) else filter(predicate, rest)" would be cleaner?

Comment: @flo yeah that would be cleaner, but that is creating a new list nevertheless. You just do not give it a name.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Scalway's answer, a logical next-step might be to optimize the recursive function to a [tail-recursive](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/tail-recursive-algorithms) one.  A recursive function could quickly build up stack frames that lead to a `StackOverflowError`, but Scala compiler is able to optimize a tail-recursive function to using only a single stack frame.

```
def filter(list: List[Int], cond: Int => Boolean): List[Int] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def loop(pending: List[Int], cumulated: List[Int]): List[Int] = pending match {
    case Nil =>
      cumulated
    case head :: tail =>
      loop(tail, if (cond(head)) head :: cumulated else cumulated)
  }
  loop(list, Nil).reverse
}
```

In case it's not obvious how the tail recursion is made possible, the provided link above describes in details the common pattern of using an `accumulator` as an additional argument of a function to achieve tail-recursion.

Since `filtering` is a common transformation applicable to almost all collections and it takes virtually no effort to make the function take a List of [generic type](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-write-scala-methods-generic-types-parameters-syntax), I'm including also a generalized snippet:

```
def filter[T](list: List[T], cond: T => Boolean): List[T] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def loop(pending: List[T], cumulated: List[T]): List[T] = pending match {
    case Nil =>
      cumulated
    case head :: tail =>
      loop(tail, if (cond(head)) head :: cumulated else cumulated)
  }
  loop(list, Nil).reverse
}
```

Testing it:

```
filter[Int](List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), _ != 3)
// res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 5)

filter[String](List("apple", "pear", "orange"), _ contains "r")
// res2: List[String] = List("pear", "orange")
```